# continue is not allowing with labels in java

Tags: java, break, continue

I am getting an error when using multiple labels together. Only the fourth declared label is allowing continue.

> continue first; is giving compiler error
>
> Why is only the forth label allowed with continue in the below code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    first: second: third: forth:
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println("outer start");
        
        for(int j =0;j<5;j++){
            System.out.println("inner");    
        }
        continue first;
    }
    System.out.println("end");
    
}
```

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: @tony How is that an infinite loop? The loop is going to exit anyway when i >=5. The continue is worthless because the loop will implicitly continue at that point. I think the real issue here is that it is not  syntactically valid for multiple labels in same statement. But I'm surprised the error isn't at that line.

Comment: I'm more surprised that my J2SE 1.8.0_144-b01 rejects `continue first` but `break first` works fine

Comment: @tony A label can be followed by another label, that is perfectly legal. It's useless, but it's legal.

Comment: @thatotherguy It makes sense when you think about what labels in Java actually are. You can break out of any statement, but you can only continue inside loop statements. Only `forth` is a label for a loop statement, all other labels are labels for a labeled statement. See my answer.

Comment: Huh. TIL you can use `break` on labelled `if` statements without a switch/loop involved.

Comment: @thatotherguy You can break from **any** labeled statement. `foobar: { break foobar; }` is valid Java. Heck, even `lulz: break lulz;` is valid.

Answer (score 2):

**This is expected behavior.** `continue` can only be used inside a *loop statement*. A *label* only ever belongs to **one** *statement*. Only the *label* `forth` belongs to the `for`-*loop statement*.

Let's look at the [language specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7):

1. The Java language defines *labels* as `LabeledStatement`, meaning they are *statements* themselves.
2. A *labeled statement* consists of the *label*, a *colon*, and a *statement*.
3. Since *labeled statements* are *statements*, you can nest them.

So what does this mean in your example:

1. The *labeled statement* `first: second: third: forth: for(;;);` is a nested labeled statement, consisting of the *label* `first` and the *statement* (*labeled statement*) `second: third: forth: for(;;);`
2. The *labeled statement* `second: third: forth: for(;;);` consists of the *label* `second` and the *statement* `third: forth: for(;;);`
3. The *labeled statement* `third: forth: for(;;);` consists of the *label* `third` and the *statement* `forth: for(;;);`
4. Finally, `forth: for(;;);` consists of the *label* `forth` and the *statement* `for(;;);`

Therefore only the *label* `forth` is the *label* of the *labeled statement* that the `for`-*loop* belongs to, and `continue` can only be used within a *loop*, not outside a *loop*.

A commenter wondered why `break: first;` works, that's because breaking is possible out of any *statement*, regardless of if the *statement* is a *loop* or not. So *breaking out* of `first` is legal, while *continuing into* it is not.